# Banach algebras for which the Gelfand transform is 1-1 but not onto

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Are there examples of Banach Algebra's for which the Gelfand transform is 1-1, (ie: the intersection of all maximal ideals of the algebra is $\{0\}$) but not onto?

#### Context

Page 96 of Kaniuth's "Course on Banach Algebras" gives an example:

> Lemma 2.7.10. Let $G$ be a locally compact Abelian group, and suppose that the Gelfand homomorphism $\Gamma : f \to  f$ from $L^1(G)$ into $C_0(G)$ is surjective. Then $G$ has to be discrete.

Other suggestions?